# Android dynamic screen splitting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

**What am I trying to do?**

Activity starts with a `ImageView` taking the upper 9/10 of the screen, and a `ListView` the remaining bottom 1/10:
[image]

As more items added to the `ListView`, the ratio changes, `ListView` getting 1/10 more of the screen for each item, and `ImageView` shrinks respectively, up to 50:50 ratio (adding more items after that keeps the ratio fixed) :
[image]

**What I already know:**
Best practice of statically dividing the screen, is using `LinearLayout` attribute `android:weightSum` (and `View`'s `android:layout_weight`). It should be possible to it dynamically as well using `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, combined with registering a callback somewhere in `ArrayAdapter`. However, it fills like an abuse of a static feature (weight). Moreover, I'd prefer to do the transition between to ratios continuously (using Property Animation).

**Questions:**

1. Should I prefer using `getWindowManager()                 .getDefaultDisplay().getHieght();` once, and calculating ratio dynamically as desired?
2. As for ratio updating callback, are there any option other than `ArrayAdapter.registerDataSetObserver()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like what you want by:

1) Set up layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_forImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_forList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) write some  Utility methods for layouting.

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}

private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

3) code:

```
int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
int screenHeight = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp);
int ratio = ....;//
setLayoutSize(ll_forImage, screenWidth , screenHeight/ratio );
setLayoutSize(ll_forList, screenWidth , screenHeight - screenHeight/ratio );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep ratio always 10% and 90%, use weight 1 and weight 9.
Otherwise better to write xml code to check

Comment: Well, I don't want to keep ratio, that's point :)     what do you mean by "write xml code to check" ? @Ahmad Ebrahimi